# If the human eye can see green so well, why don't flames and such that emit a broad rangecof wavelengths ever appear green?

Tags: optics, visible-light, everyday-life, combustion

Similar questions have been posted many, many times before, but....

If a black body at the correct (average) temperature  is 'centered' on the green, and human eyes our retinal cones) see best in the green area of the visible spectrum, then...

Why don't flames pass through a green phase with increasing temperature?

Why do they go from red to Orange to yellow to blue?

Comment: I might be incorrect, but we're not going to see something as green if it emits non-green wavelengths of light in addition to the green ones since [what we see as color has to do with how much the different cone cells in our eyes are excited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision#/media/File:Cone-fundamentals-with-srgb-spectrum.svg). That's why we can depict all sorts of colors with only red, green and blue monochromatic light sources.

Comment: I'd say probably the spectrum isn't narrow enough to appear green but rather more towards the white/yellow.

Comment: One should plot up the black body spectra for different temperatures and look at ‘green’ vs other emissions.

Comment: https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-make-green-flames-606190  also see color perception  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision#Physiology_of_color_perception

Comment: Blue propane/methane/butane etc result not from blackbody radiation but from molecular excitation

Comment: @royaljelly is on the right track.   Since something producing a near-black-body radiance curve 9with peak in the green)  will of necessity produce a lot of photons in the blue, yellow, etc. ranges,  the neuroptical response is what it is.

Comment: This sounds like two completely independent questions. (1) At what temperature would flames look green? and (2) If the human eye is most sensitive to green wavelengths, then why doesn't _everything_ look green? Question (1) is a physics question. Question (2) is more about human physiology and evolution.